# Webgl-plot gives me error when trying to plot data

Tags: javascript, html, flask, webgl

I have created a **Flask** proyect to show in real time some metrics from the computer. First I used chart.js and everything works fine.
Here is what I achived with using **chart.js**:
[image: chart.js]

This library is not as fast as I need, so after investigating i found that I could use either **uPlot** or **WebGL-plot**.

I'm trying using [webgl-plot](https://github.com/danchitnis/webgl-plot/tree/master).

This is what I've done so far. First of all this is the stucture that my proyect has:

```
-FLASK_WEBGL/
   - .venv/
   - static/
      - css/
         - base.css
         - index.css
      - scripts/
         - webgl_scripts/
            - All the scripts that appeare in the github repo under dist/
         - script_cpu.js
         - script_drive.js
         - script_ram.js
         - script_temp.js
   - templates/
      - base.html
      - index.html
   - app.py
```

My `app.py`, here I obtain all the data I need and save it in a json file:

```
import psutil, json, wmi

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


def get_cpu_temperature():
    # Code to get cpu temperature
   return temp

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/get_data")
def get_data():
    temperature = get_cpu_temperature()
    data = {
        'temp_cpu': temperature if temperature is not None else 'N/A',
        'cpu_percent': psutil.cpu_percent(),
        'ram_percent': psutil.virtual_memory().percent,
        'drive_percent': psutil.disk_usage('/').percent
    }
    return json.dumps(data)
```

In case it's needed, this is what i get in 127.0.0.1/get_data:

`{"temp_cpu": 53.8, "cpu_percent": 0.0, "ram_percent": 43.3, "drive_percent": 85.7}`

This is th `base.html` and the `index.html`:

**Base**
Here I load the `webplot.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/base.css') }}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/webgl_scripts/webglplot.js') }}"></script>

</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**Index**
For the example I'm only showing one of the elements to plot.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %} Metrics {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/index.css') }}">
    </head>

    <header>
        <h1> Computer real time metrics </h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="ram-container">
            <div class="container-title"> <h2> RAM </h2> </div>
            <div class="container-chart">
                <canvas class="canvas" id="ram-chart"> </canvas>                
                <script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/script_ram.js') }}"></script>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

Finally this is the script I've written, script_ram.js:

- First of all I create the plot where the data will be printed.
- Second I create the function `updateRAMData()` where I parse th data from the json and save it in an array called `ramData`.
- At the end I set an interval so that every 2 seconds I can get the data and graph it.

```
var ramData = [];

function generatePlotInstance() {
    const plot = new WebGLPlot();
    plot.setData(ramData);
    plot.setTitle("Gráfico de Uso de RAM");
    plot.renderTo("ram-chart");
}

function updateRAMData() {
    $.get('/get_data', function (data) {
        try {
            const parseData = JSON.parse(data);
            const ramPercent = parseData.ram_percent;
            const timestamp = Date.now();
            
            ramData.push([timestamp, ramPercent]);

            if (ramData.length > 450) { ramData.shift(); }

            generatePlotInstance();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error RAM', error);
        }        
    });
}

setInterval(updateRAMData, 2000);
```

The problem I have is that in the console log of the navigator I get this error:

```
Error RAM ReferenceError: WebGLPlot is not defined
    generatePlotInstance http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/scripts/script_ram.js:4
    updateRAMData http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/scripts/script_ram.js:21
    jQuery 7
        c
        fireWith
        l
        o
        send
        ajax
        i
    updateRAMData http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/scripts/script_ram.js:11
    setInterval handler* http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/scripts/script_ram.js:29
script_ram.js:23:21
```

And I do not know how to solve it so I can see if the code I`ve written works.